# Doing text analysis in R and I can't figure out a way to remove the "s" or other contractions out

Tags: r, nlp

I'm trying to remove the S and other contraction letters from my text data. The current preprocessing code that I am using is this:

```
x<- (demtweets$Tweet)
x <- paste(unlist(x), collapse =" ")
x <- stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "latin-ascii")

x<- gsub(" '[A-z] ", " ", x)
x <- gsub("&amp", "", x)
x <- gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", "", x)
x <- gsub("@\\w+", "", x)
x <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)
x <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x)
x <- gsub("http\\w+", "", x)
x <- gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", x)
x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) 
x <- replace_contraction(x, contraction.key = lexicon::key_contractions,
                     ignore.case = TRUE)
x <- replace_contraction(x,
                contraction = qdapDictionaries::contractions, replace = NULL,
                ignore.case = TRUE)

xdfm <-dfm(x, stem = F, remove_punct = T, tolower = T, remove_twitter = T, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove = c(stopwords("english"), "http","https","rt", "t.co"))


  textplot_wordcloud(xdfm, min_count = 6, random_order = FALSE,
               rotation = .25,
               color = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
topfeatures(xdfm, 100)
```

`

None of these commands seem to be addressing the issue. Any help?

Comment: Hello, welcome SO !  Please add a some example data (such as `dput(head(demtweets$Tweet))` so we can run your code.

Comment: Hello, welcome SO! It would be helpful if you could post some example data that go with your code, and why this code isn't working. More details on your issue would be better, rather than just a bunch of code

Comment: You probably want to "stem" the words so that you get to the root of the words instead of only removing "'s" at the end. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpus/vignettes/stemmer.html